# Can 'on' be used in a temporal setting?

Tags: prepositions

I usually replace *upon* with *on* because it sounds less pompous. Is it correct to do so when the meaning is temporal? Consider

> Languages change (up)on contacting others.

Should I replace *upon* with *when* intead?

Comment: By the way you mean *contact with others*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on#on) indicates that *on* can indeed refer to points in time.

> **8.** Indicating the day or part of a day during which an event takes place:
>   *reported on September 26
>
>    on a very hot evening in July*
>   **8.1** At the time of:
>   *she was booed on arriving home*

*Upon* is essentially the same as *on,* albeit perhaps more formal as you note.

> The preposition *upon* has the same core meaning as the preposition *on.* However, in modern English *upon* tends to be restricted to more formal contexts or to established phrases and idioms, as in *once upon a time* and *row upon row of seats.* [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upon) again]

Generally *on* denotes a specific time/day or occasion. Whether it's entirely appropriate for something more gradual or process-like such as  interaction between languages may be worth considering.

> Languages change [up]on contacting others

...says that any contact between two languages will instantaneously change both. If that's not the case — as surely it can't be — an expression which connotes a more drawn-out process might be better than either *on* or *upon*.

Comment: Would you think that reservation is implied from context? "Once speciation [of multicellular species] completes, information is isolated forever. This isn't the case in linguistics since languages change on contacting others."

Comment: Guarded yes -- as speciation is a process, the other "change" might be long-running too. But you might consider "as": "languages change as they interact with each other".

Answer (score 0):

Try *Languages change when they {abut / impinge on / rub up against} each other.*

Answer (score 0):

Here *on*  is used with the  meaning:

- at the occasion of: on his meetings.

I think  *on*  is appropriate in your sencence. *When* can be an alternative.